# Changing pictures or text box saved in Office 2010 and opened in Office 2007

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-powerpoint-2007, microsoft-powerpoint-2010

I have two computers:

1. Windows Vista and Microsoft Office 2010.
2. Windows XP service pack 3 and Microsoft Office 2007

I worked on the first computer on Office 2010 and I saved in the format `.pptx` on a USB pen drive. I closed this and I went on the second computer.

I opened the document on the second computer and I have the  following problem:

When there is a text box with a description, I can't change that description but I can add a new picture and write new text. If I go back to the first computer with the changed document. The problem is there as well.

Does anyone know what could be causing this?

**NOTE:** I thought that it might be a protection issue on the file but the permissions seem fine.

Comment: When you say, "text box with description", what do you mean? Is that an image with a caption?

Comment: Hi.
Before I write in text box and after the save, this is saved how the picture.
And after I don't changed  the textbox

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as though the first computer is saving as PPT rather than PPTX, or you're saving as a PowerPoint PICTURE presentation instead of as a regular presentation.

In PPT 2010, go to File | Options | Save
The first item in the Save pane allows you to choose the default format for PPT to save in.
Make sure it's PowerPoint Presentation and not the 97-2003 version.